# Php sort memory leak

Tags: php, memory, memory-leaks

I'm currently experiencing a strange bug with PHP. I've this function :

```
    public static function ksortRecursive(&$array, $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR)
{
    if (is_array($array) === false) {
        return;
    }

    ksort($array, $sort_flags);
    foreach ($array as &$arr) {
        static::ksortRecursive($arr, $sort_flags);
    }
}
```

And when i'm watching for its memory usage, it looks like it's wasting a lot of memory.

```
echo convert(memory_get_usage(true)); //7.5 mb
myObject->ksortRecursive($workData);
echo convert(memory_get_usage(true)); //37.5 mb
```

Everything is passed by reference witch make i don't understand the memory usage is bigger after call ...

Anyone has an idea ?

**EDIT : I've lead some tests, and it looks like the "is_array" function is responsible for this memory leak ... Someone know how to avoid this ?**

Comment: Yea, by reference to a bit of memory! And sort will need some room to breath in

Comment: Also PHP will not free memory just because it is not being used any more. It will wait until memory is requested that it does not have and then do a clean out in order to find some

Comment: But ... why is the memory not freed after the call ? oO

Comment: @Poyoman it's just how memory is in php - php isn't the greatest for handling memory, but look into garbage collector - might help :)

Comment: Looks like there is few solutions :/ I've tried to force the garbage colector routine, without any effects ...

Comment: Well ... i've lead some tests not using in_array .... this lead to memory leaks too :P ... il may be due to the recursiv function call finaly

Comment: do you ever unset vars after finished using them?

Comment: Yeah i tried too at the end of the function ... without effect nether ...